# In Haskell, when we use a do block, how does it figure out which monad to be used?

Tags: haskell

We know that the do block is just syntactic sugar. But then how does it figure out which monadic context it is in? Assume we don't use `<-` operator anywhere in the do block.

Comment: The do block is syntactic sugar for a load of function applications and lambadas so it can just use the normal type inferencer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe some "practical" examples will help:

```
foo1 = do
  print 5
  return 7
-- print belongs to the IO monad. This whole thing is in IO.

foo2 x = do
  writeTVar x 7
  return 11
-- writeTVar belongs to the STM monad. This whole thing is in STM.

foo3 = do
  let x = 5
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
-- Last line is a list expression. This whole thing is in the list monad.

foo4 = do
  put 7
  return 9
-- put is in the State monad. This whole thing is in the state monad.

foo5 = do
  x <- magic1
  y <- magic2
  return (x, y)
-- This is in whatever monad magic1 and magic2 are in.

foo6 = do
  return 13
-- Doesn't mention any monad. Works for ALL POSSIBLE MONADS!

foo7 abc def = do
  x <- abc
  y <- def
  return (x, y)
-- Runs in whatever monad abc and def run in.
-- By passing different arguments, you can CHANGE which monad that is!
```

Answer (score 10):

It uses the same general type class mechanism that is used to figure out which `+` to use or even what numeric type to use for literals. That is,
something like

```
 do
    return True
```

Will not divine the specific monad that it should use but rather just be assigned the type `Monad m => m Bool`. This *constraint* says that the do-block has the type `m Bool` for *any* `m` which happens to have implemented the `Monad` type class. Moreover, whenever this block is used, the specific instance will be inferred from the context of its use.

If we use operators that are tied to a specific `Monad`, this will force the type to become more specific. For instance, if we use `modify :: (a -> a) -> State s a -> State s ()` (I'm simplifying the type for the sake of example here) then this will force the block to have the type `State s ...`. In general, Haskell will figure out the most general type possible and make use of type class constraints to make sure that the types in question implement the appropriate operations.